# Flash Builder 4: Error #1009 in when Button is wrapped in BorderContainer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4, mxml

This is really bugging me, but I have a component where a Button is wrapped in BorderContainer. I'm passing a custom property to the component at run-time to change the label of the button but Flex is reporting the following error:

```
Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference
```

When the error occurs, Flex highlights the following code:

```
myButton.label = value;
```

Here's the app:

```
// MyApp.mxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       xmlns:local="*">
    <local:MyComp id="myButton" label="My Button"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>

// MyComp.mxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   width="400" height="300">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private var _label:String;

            public function get label():String
            {
                return _label;
            }

            public function set label(value:String):void
            {
                _label = value;
                myButton.label = value;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button id="myButton" label="Test"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `myButton` Object is not already created if the setter function for the `label` property is called the first time. Assign the new label value to `myButton.label` in `commitProperties()`.

You should read [About creating advanced components](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html) (most notably *"About the component instantiation life cycle"*) to understand why.

Comment: If I rename BorderContainer to Group and try again, it works. Any reason why BorderContainer is causing this error?

Comment: No idea. Maybe the `creationpolicy` is different.